# build loop in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas

How to animate a border around the square content.
tried to use this code but can't make it build with animation..

```
class RadialPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double progressRemoval;
  final Color color;
  final StrokeCap strokeCap;
  final PaintingStyle paintingStyle;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final double progress;
  RadialPainter(
      {this.progressRemoval,
      this.color,
      this.strokeWidth,
      this.strokeCap,
      this.paintingStyle,
      this.progress});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..color = color
      ..style = paintingStyle
      ..strokeCap = strokeCap;

    var progressRemoval = 0.50;

    var path = Path();

    //LINEA SUPERIOR DEL CUADRADO
    path.moveTo((size.width * 0.30), 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo((size.width * 0.30), 0, size.width, 0);

    //LATERAL DERECHO
    path.moveTo(size.width, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width, size.height);

    //LINEA INFERIOR DEL CUADRADO
    path.moveTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height, 0, size.height);

    //LINEA IZQUIERDA
    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, (size.height * 0.75), 0, ((size.height * 0.75)));

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RadialPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.progress != progress;
  }
}
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870939/flutter-animate-border-color-of-a-con](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870939/flutter-animate-border-color-of-a-container?rq=1)tainer?rq=1

Comment: Why are you not using the solution you have linked to? It seems to fit your use case if I have understood it correctly.

Comment: the solution that linked doesn't help, i want the border to be animate from starting point to ending point as a square around container

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541712/how-can-i-create-an-animated-rounded-rectangular-border-around-my-widget/70541713#70541713)?

Comment: yess, but without using a button. an image inside container instead of a button

Comment: The child of the `CustomPaint` doesn't have to be a button. You can use any widget really. Simply replace the `ElevatedButton` from the example with your `Container`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example for your use case with a `Container` and a repeating animation that you can run in DartPad.

For a detailed explanation see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541712/how-can-i-create-an-animated-rounded-rectangular-border-around-my-widget/70541713#70541713).

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Border Animation',
        home: Scaffold(body: ExampleOutlinePathWrapper()));
  }
}

// Example code including two animations
class ExampleOutlinePathWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ExampleOutlinePathWrapper> createState() =>
      _ExampleOutlinePathWrapperState();
}

class _ExampleOutlinePathWrapperState extends State<ExampleOutlinePathWrapper>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 2000,
      ),
    );
    _animation = _controller
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _controller.reset();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          _controller.forward();
        }
      });
    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: AnimatedBorderPainter(
              animation: _animation,
              strokeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              pathType: PathType.circle,
              animationDirection: AnimationDirection.counterclockwise,
              startingPercentage: 50,
              strokeWidth: 8.0,
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: AnimatedBorderPainter(
              animation: _animation,
              strokeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              pathType: PathType.rect,
              animationDirection: AnimationDirection.clockwise,
              startingPercentage: 25,
              strokeWidth: 4.0,
            ),
            child: Container(height: 100, width: 100, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedBorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Animation<double> _animation;
  final PathType _pathType;
  final double _strokeWidth;
  final Color _strokeColor;
  final Radius _radius;
  final int _startingPercentage;
  final AnimationDirection _animationDirection;

  AnimatedBorderPainter({
    required animation,
    PathType pathType = PathType.rect,
    double strokeWidth = 2.0,
    Color strokeColor = Colors.blueGrey,
    Radius radius = const Radius.circular(4.0),
    int startingPercentage = 0,
    AnimationDirection animationDirection = AnimationDirection.clockwise,
  })  : assert(strokeWidth > 0, 'strokeWidth must be greater than 0.'),
        assert(startingPercentage >= 0 && startingPercentage <= 100,
            'startingPercentage must lie between 0 and 100.'),
        _animation = animation,
        _pathType = pathType,
        _strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        _strokeColor = strokeColor,
        _radius = radius,
        _startingPercentage = startingPercentage,
        _animationDirection = animationDirection,
        super(repaint: animation);

  late Path _originalPath;
  late Paint _paint;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final animationPercent = _animation.value;

    // Construct original path once when animation starts
    if (animationPercent == 0.0) {
      _originalPath = _createOriginalPath(size);
      _paint = Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = _strokeWidth
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = _strokeColor;
    }

    final currentPath = _createAnimatedPath(
      _originalPath,
      animationPercent,
    );

    canvas.drawPath(currentPath, _paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(AnimatedBorderPainter oldDelegate) => true;

  Path _createOriginalPath(Size size) {
    switch (_pathType) {
      case PathType.rect:
        return _createOriginalPathRect(size);
      case PathType.rRect:
        return _createOriginalPathRRect(size);
      case PathType.circle:
        return _createOriginalPathCircle(size);
    }
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathRect(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      )
      ..lineTo(0, -(_strokeWidth / 2));
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(
          originalPath, PathType.rect, size);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathRRect(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
          _radius,
        ),
      );
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(originalPath, PathType.rRect);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathCircle(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addOval(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      );
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(originalPath, PathType.circle);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }

  Path _createPathForStartingPercentage(Path originalPath, PathType pathType,
      [Size? size]) {
    // Assumes that original path consists of one subpath only
    final pathMetrics = originalPath.computeMetrics().first;
    final pathCutoffPoint = (_startingPercentage / 100) * pathMetrics.length;
    final firstSubPath = pathMetrics.extractPath(0, pathCutoffPoint);
    final secondSubPath =
        pathMetrics.extractPath(pathCutoffPoint, pathMetrics.length);
    if (pathType == PathType.rect) {
      Path path = Path()
        ..addPath(secondSubPath, Offset.zero)
        ..lineTo(0, -(_strokeWidth / 2))
        ..addPath(firstSubPath, Offset.zero);
      switch (_startingPercentage) {
        case 25:
          path.lineTo(size!.width + _strokeWidth / 2, 0);
          break;
        case 50:
          path.lineTo(size!.width - _strokeWidth / 2, size.height);
          break;
        case 75:
          path.lineTo(0, size!.height + _strokeWidth / 2);
          break;
        default:
      }
      return path;
    }
    return Path()
      ..addPath(secondSubPath, Offset.zero)
      ..addPath(firstSubPath, Offset.zero);
  }

  Path _createAnimatedPath(
    Path originalPath,
    double animationPercent,
  ) {
    // ComputeMetrics can only be iterated once!
    final totalLength = originalPath
        .computeMetrics()
        .fold(0.0, (double prev, PathMetric metric) => prev + metric.length);

    final currentLength = totalLength * animationPercent;

    return _extractPathUntilLength(originalPath, currentLength);
  }

  Path _extractPathUntilLength(
    Path originalPath,
    double length,
  ) {
    var currentLength = 0.0;

    final path = Path();

    var metricsIterator = _animationDirection == AnimationDirection.clockwise
        ? originalPath.computeMetrics().iterator
        : originalPath.computeMetrics().toList().reversed.iterator;

    while (metricsIterator.moveNext()) {
      var metric = metricsIterator.current;

      var nextLength = currentLength + metric.length;

      final isLastSegment = nextLength > length;
      if (isLastSegment) {
        final remainingLength = length - currentLength;
        final pathSegment = _animationDirection == AnimationDirection.clockwise
            ? metric.extractPath(0.0, remainingLength)
            : metric.extractPath(
                metric.length - remainingLength, metric.length);

        path.addPath(pathSegment, Offset.zero);
        break;
      } else {
        // There might be a more efficient way of extracting an entire path
        final pathSegment = metric.extractPath(0.0, metric.length);
        path.addPath(pathSegment, Offset.zero);
      }

      currentLength = nextLength;
    }

    return path;
  }
}

enum PathType {
  rect,
  rRect,
  circle,
}

enum AnimationDirection {
  clockwise,
  counterclockwise,
}
```

Comment: Just added an example for `PathType.circle` and also simplified the code a fair bit.